# Variable name from a preprocessor concatenation"##"

Tags: c++, templates, preprocessor

I would like to create a variable name from a template argument :

```
template<typename Name>
class NotWorking {
public:
  int var_ ## Name;
};
```

Which should work like so :

```
NotWorking nw<test>;
nw.var_test;
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: That's not possible with templates. You need to use the preprocessor to do this.

Comment: If you need to do this, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I guess I can just use #define to map desired variable names to generic names.

Comment: What's wrong with non-template `Working nw_test; nw_test.var;`?

Comment: The problem is that the member variable name is very generic. Because it is so generic the classes which inherit it use variable names which have no relationship to their actual abstraction. In this example, if I do nw_test.var ... what is "var" ? a variable ! ... how would it relate to my inheriting class ... not clear ... 'var' is just too generic.